# npm install, npm -v, sudo npm install do nothing

Tags: 14.04, package-management, npm

> ```
> ~/nodecode$ sudo apt-get install
> ```
>
> npm is already the newest version. 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to
>   remove and 17 not to upgrade.>  Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information...

Having established that npm is installed I don't know why none of the listed commands do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: run these commands add the output to your question: `whereis npm`, `which npm`

Comment: `npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/X11/npm /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/share/npm /usr/share/man/man1/npm.1.gz /usr/share/man/man3/npm.3.gz`
and
`/usr/local/bin/npm`
man npm : VERSION 4.3.0

Comment: everything is ok.  what if you ran `/usr/bin/npm --version` or `/usr/bin/npm -v`

Comment: `/usr/bin/npm -v` returns: 1.3.10

Comment: I stopped trying to develop locally now. I am using cloud services instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su

root@PC_NAME:/home/# : sudo apt-get
```

You need to have nodecode folder in directory else you will get

> bash: /root/nodecode$: No such file or directory

Info:

> **apt-get** is a command line interface for retrieval of packages and
>   information about them from authenticated sources and for
>   installation, upgrade and removal of packages together with their
>   dependencies.
>
> **npm is installed with Node.js** npm is distributed with Node.js- which
>   means that when you download Node.js, you automatically get npm
>   installed on your computer. For checking the version of npm

**StepI** Install your nodejs

https://nodejs.org/en/

**Ubuntu**

Run the following on your command line to install the source for nodejs

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo -E bash -
```

Then, run this to get the latest nodejs package

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**Step II**
Check that you have node and npm installed

To check if you have Node.js installed, run this command in your terminal:

```
node -v
```

To confirm that you have npm installed you can run this command in your terminal:

```
npm -v
```

**A note on versions**

npm versions

> npm is a separate project from Node.js, and tends to update more
>   frequently. As a result, even if you’ve just downloaded Node.js (and
>   therefore npm), you’ll probably need to update your npm. Luckily, npm
>   knows how to update itself! To update your npm, type this into your
>   terminal:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

> Node versions and Long Term Support Node.js has lots of versions! To
>   use Node.js, and therefore npm, effectively, you’ll want to make sure
>   that you are on a version that is supported by the Node.js team. In
>   general, you should use the version of Node.js labelled “LTS”.
>
> Use a Node.js version manager Software is always changing, and so it’s
>   often a good practice to use a version manager to help account for
>   this change. For this reason (and many others!) we recommend that you
>   use a version manager for your Node.js installation. There are many
>   great options; here are a few*:
>
> NVM
>
> nodist
>
> n
>
> nave

All References from

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm?utm_source=house&utm_medium=homepage&utm_campaign=free%20orgs&utm_term=Install%20npm)

Comment: I will recommend you to update to 16.04 LTS